# DSSS and DQPSK receiver

Tags: digital-communications

I use a spread spectrum communication with a DQPSK modulation. Each modulation symbol is spread with a different spreading sequence. At reception, I use a sliding window for despreading with the different sequences.

1. Is this reception method feasible in a real case? Wouldn't there be a recovery timing problem in practice?
2. After despreading, if the frequency drift is different between each DQPSK symbol. I would like to know how to solve this problem?
   ​